# Known root caused for BigQuery JDBC DatabaseMetadata requests to fail. [Simba][JDSI](20560) Unexpected error while sorting metadata

Tags: jdbc

A specific Google BigQuery account fails when requests for metadata are performed via the Google BigQuery JDBC driver.

Using the same driver builds and tests but other Google BigQuery accounts work.

Which implies an issue specific to the connection being used.

Person who ran into the issue posted it to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74345950

Hence, looking for know root causes which can cause the driver to fail.

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]JDSI Unexpected error while sorting metadata.
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSIMetadataResultSet.(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSIDataEngine.getMetadataResultImplementation(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQDataEngine.getMetadataResultImplementation(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSIDataEngine.makeNewMetadataResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.jdbc41.S41DatabaseMetaData.createMetaDataResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SDatabaseMetaData.getCatalogs(Unknown Source)
    enter code here